# Is there a software package that can compute the 1-dimensional preimage of a point?

Tags: rootfinding, derivative

I have a smooth function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and points $x_0, y_0$ with
$F(x_0) = y_0$.
For theoretical reasons, I know that $y_0$ is a *regular value* of $F$,
which means that the Jacobian at every point that maps to $y_0$ has full rank
$n{-}1$.
Since $y_0$ is a regular value, the preimage $F^{-1}(y_0)$ is a 1-dimension manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
For theoretical reasons, I know that this preimage is a smooth loop.

I wonder whether there is a numerical routine that can take these as input:

- a function that computes $F(x)$
- a function that computes the Jacobian $DF(x)$
- $x_0$ and $y_0$
- an integer $M$

and then returns $M$ points, in order, on the smooth loop $F^{-1}(y_0)$.
The returned set should begin with the given point $x_0$,
and be uniformly distributed on the loop in some natural way.

Thank you so much

---

Added later:
@lightxbulb. Following your approach, I have written a routine that is working well enough for me.

1. This step computes the "extra singular vector" $u$ of $DF(x_k)$, and
   interprets it as a unit tangent vector to the loop at $x_k$. There
   are 2 such vectors, so to pick one for consistency, it does a sign test.  It adds $u$, as a new bottom
   row, to the $(n{-}1) \times n$ Jacobian matrix $DF(x_k)$. and then computes the determinant of
   the new $n \times n$ matrix. If this is negative, $u$ is reversed.
   Set $z = x_k + \tau u$.  I think it may be possible to devise
   a different sign test that uses an $(n{-}1) \times (n{-}1)$ determinant, but I
   haven't tried that yet.
2. For the projection step, instead of using the pseudo-inverse, it
   uses an n'th constraint: the projected point must lie on the
   hyperplane through $z$ with normal $u$.  It then uses a
   "canned" Newton-Raphson n-dimensional rootfinder to find $x_{k+1}$.

In summary, to go from $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$, first there is a move in the direction $u$,
and then a move orthogonal to $u$.  The intermediate point $z$ is discarded.

I am not using the integer $M$ at this time.

Comment: "Numerical continuation" is a keyword that comes to mind

Comment: Check this out: https://juliaintervals.github.io/pages/tutorials/tutorialConstraintProgramming/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read any literature on the subject, so there are likely much better approaches, but here's a sketch of what you can do. You have a set defined as $S = \{x \in\mathbb{R}^n \,:\, F(x)-y_0 = 0\}$. The kernels of $DF$ at points of $S$ give you the tangent spaces to $S$. Using this knowledge you can iterate the following process:

1. Compute $DF(x_k)$, and do a step $z_{k+1} = x_k + \tau n$ where $n$ is a unit vector in the kernel of $DF(x_k)$ (e.g. if you compute the SVD that is the extra singular vector that corresponds to no singular value). $(x_k, x_k+s n)$ for $s\in\mathbb{R}$ gives you the tangent space at $x_k$.
2. Project $z_{k+1}$ onto $S$ by iteratively solving $F(z) = y_0$ with an initial guess $z = z_{k+1}$. Set $x_{k+1}=z$.

You can try to use Newton-Rhapson for finding the projection in step 2: $z = z - (DF(z))^{+}F(z)$, with initial guess $z=z_{k+1}$. Here $(DF(z))^{+}$ is to be understood as the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, e.g. you could use CGNR to compute its application to $F(z)$.

Step one is essentially something like explicit Euler, where you say $\frac{dx}{dt} = n(x)$ and you discretize this as $z_{k+1} = x_k + \tau n(x_k)$. If you don't do step two and you set $x_{k+1} = z_{k+1}$ then assuming your steps are small enough you should get something close to the curve, but explicit Euler has stability issues. Step 2 is implementing something like implicit Euler with a guess given by explicit Euler. You can of course generalize that to an arbitrary time stepping scheme. Just pick you favourite discretisation of $\frac{dx}{dt} = n(x)$ where $n(x)$ is the singular vector corresponding to the kernel for $DF(x)$. After you are done you can pick out the $M$ points you desire, potentially by sampling some interpolant of the intermediate points you got from the time-stepping.

Generally $n(x_k)$ can be chosen in two ways when $DF(x_k)$ is of rank $n-1$, and you would generally choose the one consistent with the previous step. If $DF(x_k)$ is of rank less than $n-1$ then we can choose $n(x_k)$ in infinitely many ways. You could try to make it smoothly varying, e.g. by projecting the $n(x_{k-1})$ from the previous step onto the kernel of $DF(x_k)$, and find the new $n(x_k)$ in such a way. In the worst case scenario the projection may be zero, but then I would argue that you took a step that is too large. There may be some pathological scenarios where this doesn't work even when the step is small enough (e.g. if $S$ is not differentiable or is even discontinuous) but then $DF$ would not really be a representation of the total derivative either.

Also since you know that's a loop, at the initial point you can start two evolutions $\frac{dx}{dt} = n$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = -n$ where initially you have $n(x_0)$ of course. Evolving both may allow you to connect them at the other side of the loop and may be more accurate, sine you know that $x_0 \in S$.

Comment: It certainly looks like this approach will work.  But I was hoping for an existing routine in a public package.   If one could *always* "choose the one [the unit vector] with the previous step", then it appears that we have defined a smooth unit vector field.  And we are solving a special ODE - an ODE with n-1  "conservation laws".  Does that make sense ?  Maybe the place to look for packages is ODE solvers that support many conservation laws ?

Comment: Oops !   I should have written ""choose the one [the unit vector] *consistent* with the previous step".

Comment: @GlennDavis I think your interpretation makes sense but I don't know of any packages. The way I described the ODE problem it is certainly an evolution along a smooth vector field. Of course maybe there is another way to constrain the choice of $n$ but I felt that the smoothness assumption is the most natural, hence why I suggested projecting $n(x_k)$ onto the tangent space at $x_{k+1}$ in order to find $n(x_{k+1})$. You can achieve the latter by using again CGNR by the way (if you solve $Aw = n(x_k)$ with CGNR with an initial guess $x=0$ it gives you $w = A^+n(x_k)$, then $n_{k+1} = AA^+n_k$).